# base64 encoding string with special char in python

Tags: python, encoding, base64

I'm trying to encode a string using like so:

```
base64.b64encode(b'username\with\backslash:password')
```

but printing only the string results in this

```
print('username\\with\\backslash:password')
>> username\withackslash:password
```

When escaping the backslashes with another backslash it prints this

```
print('username\\with\\backslash:password')
>> username\with\backslash:password
```

which looks good.
But when base64 encoding and afterwards decoding it adds the extra slashes though

```
encoded=base64.b64encode(b'username\\with\\backslash:password')
print(encoded)
print(base64.b64decode(encoded))

>> b'dXNlcm5hbWVcd2l0aFxiYWNrc2xhc2g6cGFzc3dvcmQ='
>> b'username\\with\\backslash:password'
```

It encodes the escaping characters as well.

The same without escaping

```
encoded=base64.b64encode(b'username\with\backslash:password')
print(encoded)
print(base64.b64decode(encoded))

>> b'dXNlcm5hbWVcd2l0aAhhY2tzbGFzaDpwYXNzd29yZA=='
>> b'username\\with\x08ackslash:password'
```

Anyone got me a hint on how to encoding this right?
I need this for http request authorization headers and my encoded strings won't be accepted so far.

Comment: You get the same thing out that you put in, the *literal* `b'username\\with\\backslash:password'`. There are only two backslashes total in there. The reason that it doesn't look like the *string* example you have at the beginning is that it's not a string, it's a `bytes`, which is always printed as a literal, not as the pure string contents. Try `print(base64.b64decode(encoded).decode())` to print a *string*.

Comment: @deceze
namePw='username\\with\\backslash:password'
encoded=base64.b64encode(str.encode(namePw))
print(encoded.decode())
print(base64.b64decode(encoded).decode())

A better way? Looks good in the results. Thanks.